# apply(): what do square brackets mean with a function in-between?

Tags: javascript, apply

I've [found](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/delegation-vs-inheritance-in-javascript/) some piece of code, that seems to be working, but I don't understand one of its aspects.

```
> [].forEach.apply('javascript', [function(char) {
... console.log(`give me… ${char.toUpperCase()}`);
... }]);
give me a… J
give me a… A
give me a… V
give me a… A
give me a… S
give me a… C
give me a… R
give me a… I
give me a… P
give me a… T
```

Why do we need the second set of these square brackets here, what do they mean? I've never seen a function to put it there. Thanks.

Comment: @Svenskunganka I think OP is referring to the second set of square brackets

Comment: @Phil Yeah I was unsure, hence why it says *"Possible duplicate"*. Reading the title more closely makes things a bit clearer :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) expects 2 arguments.

1. The `this` argument.
2. An array of arguments to be passed to the function.

So the function is put in an array, because the `apply` function needs an array of arguments. Basically, your code is passing 1 argument, which is a function.

However, you would replace `.apply` with `.call`, and then an array of arguments would not be necessary, you could just add multiple arguments to the `.call` functions.

```
[].forEach.call('javascript', function(char) {
  console.log(`give me… ${char.toUpperCase()}`);
});
```

`.apply` is mostly useful when you have an existing array of arguments or you don't know how many you will pass, which was trick pre-ES6 syntax.